# Cannot build react-native-elements due to old react-native-vector-icons version

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

A recent removal of old gradle repos by Google has crippled older versions of some repositories, including react-native-vector-icons before version 6.1.

The react-native-elements library uses version 4.4.2 of this library.  Is there a graceful way (that is, other than hand-modifying the contents of the repo in node_modules) to overcome this problem without waiting for a new release of react-native-elements?

Comment: Isn't adding the following lines of code to the build gradle working for your case?
`subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}`